# Can I pass args in the html tag of my custom angular element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular 1, I have a directive being returned as an element called "store". So the store element will ng-repeat through each object in an array of json I am using to store all of my products.

```
<div class="list-group">
  <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <h3>{{product.name}} <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}} Spaces left: {{product.spots}}</em></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works fine on one of my pages where I want to angular repeat through all of the objects. On another page though I want to show the same information but I only want to show certain products. For example, if the key value for feature is set to true.

Is there a way in my  tag to pass arguments to specify that I only want to display the first two elements in the array or only display it if it equals a certain key value?

Comment: you should use filters for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) in your `ng-repeat` directive:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products | query:feature | limitTo:5">
    <h3>{{product.name}} <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}} Spaces left: {{product.spots}}</em></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can pass arguments to your custom directives as well. Where you define your directive, you can write:

```
return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            max: '=',
        },
        ...
        template: '
        <div class="list-group">
          <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products | query:feature | limitTo:max">
            <h3>{{product.name}} <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}} Spaces left: {{product.spots}}</em></h3>
          </div>
        </div>'
        };
```

And now you can write:

```
<store max="5" />
```

This will iterate over the first 5 elements in the array and only display them if `feature` is true.

Comment: That definitely gets me somewhere, but the issue is I have two pages where the <store></store> element is being used. Changing the template like that would alter both pages and I only want to alter one of them to show if feature is true. Would it be best to just create another template for the second page?

Comment: Updated my answer... let me know if that gets you on the right track.

Comment: Excellent, and I found the section of the documentation for exactly what you are talking about. Thank you!